# Java: How do I do indexOf in an arraylist while looking for two arguments

Tags: java, arraylist

I am currently writing a Java BlueJ project to create a poker game, and i need to set up a class for a Hand that's holding cards. I've set up a deck class that just basically generates 52 cards in order. each card has two parameters, a rank, and a suit. What i do in my hand class is I take a random card from the deck (or rather create one), and just so that I don't have copies, I want to be able to remove that card from the Deck. seeing as the cards produced are random, I'm not sure how i can take that card and remove it from the deck. Is there any way to take the card I just generated into my hand and take it out of my Deck using remove() and/or indexOf? (**Keep in mind that both the deck and the hand class are ArrayLists**)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to remove random cards from a deck is to first shuffle the deck,

```
java.util.Collections.shuffle(...)
```

will do the job for you.

then take the 0th card from the deck, via `deck.remove(0)` which will return the random Card which was removed from the deck, and then place it in the hand.

i.e.,

```
java.util.Collections.shuffle(deck); // do this just once when needed

// then later in code
hand.add(deck.remove(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

shuffle() is one way to go but it shuffles all the entries.  A more efficient way is to select a random element.

```
Random rand = new Random();

List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
// add cards

// remove a random card.
Card card1 = deck.remove(rand.nextInt(deck.size())); 
Card card2 = deck.remove(rand.nextInt(deck.size()));
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It mirrors reality but you have to select 51 random numbers and swaps for a full shuffle.  If you are only going to select a hand of say 5 cards, you might be doing 1/10th of the work.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You can do things in a computer in a virtual way which you can't do with real things.  In the case of shuffling the cards, you are are also using it as your randomizer.

Answer (score 0):

Hovercraft is right.  Collections.shuffle() is the way to go.

However, instead of having 2 ArrayLists, you should make a separate object and put those objects in the ArrayList.  Then use a Comparable implementation to sort them with Collections.sort().